# Problems with PostAsJsonAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm scratching my head with a problem, the method PostAsJsonAsync returns a 500 internal server error, but the JSON that the method is trying to send is correct since when I use Postman I send the same JSON and the server receives it, I read all questions I found about the subject and I can't find where the heck is my problem, I'm running as localhost, here is the code snippet:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endPoint);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("ZUMO-API-VERSION",2.0.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("RM-EXT-KEY", key);

var content  = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NotifiedUser), 
                   Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(endPoint, content);
```

I already checked and TryAddWithoutValidation is returning true for both instances so every parameter for the PostAsJsonAsync method are correct.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to convert class to json string. You can directly pass the class object to the method PostAsJsonAsync. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I know , It was like that before and that does not fix anything só I thought the method was serializing in a weird way and did the serialization before entering the method in order to check It but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just `client.SendAsync` instead of `client.PostAsJsonAsync(endPoint, content)`?
I had a similar issue talking to external java services and `PostAsJson` returned 400, but when changed to:

```
var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
{
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apdRequest), Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json")
};

var response = client.SendAsync(request2).Result;
```

it started working...

It appears to be something where `PostAsJsonAsync` is not doing the serialization correctly -- but is not giving any indication of a problem.