# Call webAPI method synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I want to call a webAPI method from a windows service and I do not need to said call to be async. If I do handle this call in a async manner, I am going to have to propagate async all the way up my call chain which I prefer not to do. Instead, I want the method to be called synchronously.

Everywhere I look the answer is just put async all through your code (I do not want, or need this) or to use a work around [described here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). I thought that there would be a more clean way to simply call webAPI methods from a windows service without doing either of those options. Am I missing something or is it just the way it is?

I know from reading other posts and that article that doing the following code is bad and can deadlock, but I imagined by now there would be a better way to 'fix' this other than using a hack. Is there a current preferred method that has been added in the latest .NET version?

```
public void Send(MeasurementProcessResults measurementResult)
{
    var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/notification", measurementResult).Result;

    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Do some stuff here
    }
    else
    {
        //throw an exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with how to decorate a async method and use `await` and have a `Task` you should review how to create async methods as well as how and where to use them..

Comment: @MethodMan Read his entire post. Your comment ignores his clear request for a synchronous solution and desire to not decorate his methods as `async`

Comment: then he should not use async calls..

Comment: @MethodMan There is not an available `PostAsJsonSync` for the `HttpClient`

Comment: look at this linq and you should be able to do it this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750451/send-http-post-message-in-asp-net-core-using-httpclient-postasjsonasync

Comment: here as well for a work around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270596/problems-with-postasjsonasync-method

Comment: http://developmentfootprints.blogspot.com/2013/03/net-httpclient-synchronous-post-get.html

Comment: What if just not use HttpClient?

Comment: @Evk I would be fine with that too

Comment: [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) has sync methods

Comment: How about making the send function Async as usual and calling th function using : Send().Wait();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) that has synchronous methods for calling rest services natively.